# Fastify: avoiding writing boiler plate handler in every routes

Tags: fastify

Is there a possibility in [Fastify](https://github.com/fastify/fastify) to avoid writing the similar handler always?

My handler looks like (a proxy sort of):

```js
handler: async (request, reply) => {           
      reply.from(proxyMap[request.url]);
      return reply;
}
```

where the `proxyMap` is just a mapping of my proxy routes to target/upstream route path. However the handler is always same.

Say a sample `proxyMap` content can be:

```js
  const proxyMap = {
      "/api/path1/proxy1" : "/api/backend/api1",
      "/api/path2/proxy2" : "/api/backend/api2",
          ....
  };
```

How can I move to handler somewhere common (say in some lifecycle hook or somewhere appropriate) such that every route I need not to write it. Like when I will write the route, it will be executed based on the proxyMap look up.

Is there a way in fastify to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate it with some coding:

```js
async function handler(request, reply) {
  reply.from(proxyMap[request.url])
  return reply
}

const proxyMap = {
  '/api/path1/proxy1': '/api/backend/api1',
  '/api/path2/proxy2': '/api/backend/api2',
}

Object.keys(proxyMap).forEach((url) => {
  fastify.get(url, { handler })
})
```

Comment: Preety  Thanks.